# Looking for games with drop-in drop-out mechanic

Tags: game-design, mechanics

When playing video games, I often prefer games that are easy to drop in and drop out of.  Games like Team Fortress 2 where players are always respawning so the new player isn't set back, especially if most people are ignoring the goal.

With board games I sometimes see two problems:  Sometimes the game stretches on longer than one player can afford or care for (I usually have a 1 hour rule for myself).  Sometimes the game has already been started and another prospective player shows up.

In these circumstances it would be nice if a game carried on even though players might start or stop playing at any time.  Are there any board games out there with good drop-in drop-out mechanics?

Comment: Hey tugs, sorry I closed your question.  Per our [faq] recommendation questions are not on topic here.  They aren't a good fit for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

Fluxx and a few other social card games allow players to join or leave at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Mansions of Madness. With one change to the rules.

The rules currently have the keeper draw threat for the number of investigators that started the game. This would have to be modified to be the number of players currently playing the game instead of investigators.

This way the threat accumulation would be accurate to the amount of players.

other than that a new investigator could join in at any time because the game has a time limit and it is not dependent on the players still being around to complete, with the exception of the keeper.

Arkham Horror could also be dropped into and out of.

Comment: And Elder Sign. :)

Answer (score 1):

Coup you could just deal the new person 2 cards and start them with 3 cash, or just wait the few mins until the round is over and include them in the next one. The rounds are short enough that no-one will be waiting long to join.